# How to prevent this regex that replaces hyphens with spaces from also replacing hyphens with additional hyphens?

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex:

```
str.replace(/ +/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

will convert this:

```
The dog jumped over the lazy - chair
```

into this:

```
the-dog-jumped-over-the-lazy---chair
```

How to modify it so it produces this instead (only a single hyphen):

```
the-dog-jumped-over-the-lazy-chair
```

Comment: It does not replace the hyphen with extra hyphens for me. Are you sure that is your exact regex or that is your exact input string?

Comment: The original question had a typo. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your actual input is "The dog jumped over the lazy - chair", with spaces around that hyphen getting converted, since there's no other reason the pattern should match there.

Try this:

```
str.replace(/( +- *)|(- +)|( +)/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

That explicitly checks for strings of spaces on either side of hyphens (the first pattern is also designed to consume trailing space), consuming exactly one hyphen in the process. If a hyphen already exists surrounded by spaces, that hyphen is included in the match, so when a hyphen is written, it is simply a "replacement"; in this case, the spaces are simply removed, and the hyphen is re-created by the replace operation because it is captured as part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Include hyphens in the regexp.

```
str.replace(/[ -]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will destroy any group of consecutive hyphens that already exists. This may be desired, but if your input string is "What---impossible!", the result will be "what-impossible!", instead of preserving the extra hyphens. If the correct output for "What---impossible!" (or, for that matter, "What--- impossible!") is "what---impossible!", you need the slightly more elaborate regex in my solution.